# Opencv Resize Cancel/Stop

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, resize

Can you cancel/stop a resize function? Say if it is resizing an image for 4 seconds and I would like to cancel it after 2 seconds (timing does not matter) because I do not want to resize this particular image, is there a method of doing so?

```
cvResize(srcImg, dstImg, CV_INTER_AREA);   //Cancel this function
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a platform that supports POSIX threads, you could start a new thread to
perform the `cvResize` operation, then use [`pthread_cancel`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html) if you need to stop
it before it runs to completion.  There's nothing built into standard C++ or OpenCV
to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

What @Jim says is the way to go. But another approach that might work for you is simply to check the size of the image before executing `cvResize()`. You probably know which image takes 4 seconds to process, so what you can do is always check the size of the image and if it's *too big*, you just don't call `cvResize()`.

Comment: or leave the decision to the user. i don't understand why almost all developers nowadays fail to think of the user as the one in charge.  instead they try let their software make decisions on behalf of the helpless, lobotomized user... like the microsoft office clip. IMPRESSION FIXUP: that idea of *not* calling is profoundly good. But I'd leave that decision to user. :-)